# ReactJS - Objects Adding Twice During SetState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a form that would submit a ticket. The deal is, I have a view of these tickets, and I have a button to choose between two filters - either tickets the user owns, or all tickets that need to be worked. It seems, however, that when I try to optimistically add a ticket to the current TicketList with setState that the new ticket is added TWICE - it's at the top of the list, and at the bottom. I'm kinda stumped on how that can happen. Here is my ticket submit function:

```
handleTicketSubmit(ticket) {
        const tickets = this.state.data;
        // Optimistically set an id on the new ticket. It will be replaced by an
        // id generated by the server. In a production application you would likely
        // use a more robust system for ID generation.
        var assUser = ticket.AssignedTo[0];
        var newTicket = tickets[0];
        newTicket.id = tickets.length + 1;
        newTicket.userOwnerId = assUser.id;
        newTicket.summary = ticket.Summary;
        newTicket.description = ticket.Description;
        //alert(assUser.id);
        //alert(JSON.stringify(newTicket));
        //ticket.id = tickets.length + 1;
        //ticket.userOwnerId = assUser.id;
        //alert("Before: " + JSON.stringify(tickets.length));
        const newTickets = tickets.concat([newTicket]);
        //alert("After: " + JSON.stringify(newTickets.length));
        alert("Before: " + this.state.selectedData.length);
        if (assUser.id == this.userState.data.id) {
            var myTix = this.state.data.filter(x => x.userOwnerId == newTicket.userOwnerId);
            alert(JSON.stringify(myTix));
            if (myTix.length == this.state.selectedData.length) {
                this.setState({ selectedData: newTickets });
            }
        }
        else {
            this.setState({ selectedData: newTickets });
        }

        //this.setState({ data: newTickets });
        //alert(JSON.stringify(ticket));
        const data = new FormData();
        data.append('Summary', ticket.Summary);
        data.append('Description', ticket.Description);
        data.append('AssignedTo', assUser.id);

        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('post', this.props.submitUrl, true);
        xhr.onload = () => this.loadTicketsFromServer();
        xhr.send(data);
    }
```

selectedData is an array that can change based on the filter option the user chooses - either his/her own tickets, or all tickets. Here's the props constructor for the JSX:

```
class Queue extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { data: this.props.initialData, closedData: this.props.closedData, selectedData: this.props.initialData, matchedUserNames: [] };
        this.handleTicketSubmit = this.handleTicketSubmit.bind(this);
        this.toJavaScriptDate = this.toJavaScriptDate.bind(this);
        this.userState = { data: this.props.userData };
        this.usersCollection = { data: this.props.userDB };
        this.getUsername = this.getUsername.bind(this);
        this.serverMsg = { data: this.props.serverMsg };
        this.srvMsgRst = { data: this.props.srvMsgRst };
        this.showAllTickets = this.showAllTickets.bind(this);
        this.showMyTickets = this.showMyTickets.bind(this);
        this.checkServerMessage = this.checkServerMessage.bind(this);
        this.showAssignModal = this.showAssignModal.bind(this);
        this.filterUsers = this.filterUsers.bind(this);
        this.handleUserAssign = this.handleUserAssign.bind(this);
        this.selectedCheck = this.selectedCheck.bind(this);
    }
```

In case anyone is curious, here is the ticketList component being rendered in the Queue component:

```
<TicketList data={this.state.selectedData} getTicket={this.props.navUrl} renderDate={this.toJavaScriptDate} checkUser={this.getUsername} />
```

Would anyone have an idea of what's happening? When I try to update the state of selectedData, again, it adds at both the beginning and end of selectedData, and when I DON'T call this, nothing happens. When I tried debugging by calling on an alert after changing the selectedData's state, the length appears to be the same as before it was changed for some reason.

Comment: Keep in mind that setState is an asynchronous function. To do anything only after the state is set you have use a callback as second parameter to it.

Comment: what is the handleSubmit doing? the new FormData(), data.append stuff. B/c you are setting state to the new ticket then appending the same data to whatever the FormData stuff does. So that sticks out as being somewhere that you are adding the same ticket data twice.

Comment: @Jameson it's merely setting the state of the selected data on the page, and then the formData() sends it as a post to a ticket creator method on the server. Thing is, I don't see it change when I have that setState code commented out until I refresh the page.

Comment: you could try adding a console.trace() inside the handleSubmit to see if it's being called twice. Console.trace() would tell u where its being called from/

Comment: @Jameson using console.trace() shows it only being called once :(

Comment: have u checked if issue is server side?